# How to add myself to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I am a server administrator. And I used my account to setup SQL Server 2012. 
Unfortunately, I removed myself from SQL Server. I don't have any backup account or `sa`. So, I can't log in to SQL Server now.

How can I re-add myself to SQL Server?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are there any remaining administrator accounts?

Comment: @samiles: No. Only one account I have. I also did not use SQL account mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being local Windows administrator, you can always access SQL Server with sysadmin rights starting server in single user mode (-m). Of course you don't need to reinstall SQL Server. Step by step instructions are in the article [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out)

Comment: Greate! Thank you! I did it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Window Authentication Mode to Access

Else

You'll have to reinstall the server as there is no "grip" available to run anything to restore the accounts or create new ones.

Since you can't backup your databases either (again, no way to get there from here) you'll want to stop the SQL Server service (MSSQLSERVER) in the Services panel so that it releases its exclusive lock on your database files. Next, navigate to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data and copy all of the MDF and LDF files to a safe spot.

Next, uninstall and re-install SQL Server (you may be able to just reinstall). Once you are up and running again, copy the MDF/LDF files back (NOT the model, msdb or master databases!! Just the ones that YOU have created) and "attach" them in a SQL window. You'll do all of this with the Windows integrated account.